# x64dbg plugin Scylla error - "cannot dump image"

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, x64dbg

As a RE noob, I am trying to follow [this blog post](https://secret.club/2019/01/09/reverse-engineering-bdo-1.html) about reverse engineering Black Desert, but it seems like Scylla, a default plugin in x64dbg, is not working for me as it throws the error ("cannot dump image") as shown below.

[image]

The program I was trying to get the binary dump out of is the executable of Black Desert game (BlackDesert64.exe), and I am running the debugger on Windows10.

Any other buttons for Pick DLL, IAT Autosearch, or Get Imports also gave me nothing. What am I missing?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there is any other information I can add on for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, "Use PE header from disk" is active.

Comment: Note: if the game process is running as administrator, make sure you run x64dbg also as administrator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).